# Why we are using shape=((None,)+image_shape) below what does that mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

what does `shape=((None,)+image_shape)` mean below?

```
tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=((None,)+image_shape),name="x")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(None, ) + image_shape` is tuple addition. `(None, )` is a tuple of one element, and the addition will produce something like `(None, 1920, 1080)`

The `None` in numpy arrays is a special value, which means that you want to add a new dimension. So, the original `image[i, j]` pixel will become `image[0, i, j]` in the new array